# How to use `arguments` where Parameters<...> or similar is expected

Tags: typescript, parameters, arguments

Is there a way to use `arguments` of `Some Function` where `Parameters<Some Function>` is expected without asserting etc.?

ex.

```js
function f(a:number, b:number){
    let args:Parameters<typeof f> = arguments // Error: Type 'IArguments' is not assignable to type '[a: number, b: number]'.
}
```

ex.

```js
function fx(a:number, b:number){
    fy(...arguments); // Error: Type 'IArguments' is not assignable to type '[a: number, b: number]'.
  
}

function fy(a:number, b:number){
    console.log(arguments);
}
```

Comment: You can't; strongly-typed `arguments` is a missing feature of TypeScript, requested at [ms/TS#29055](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29055).  The only way to do this is with the equivalent of a type assertion (what you're calling "casting"), but since you eliminated that option in the question, the answer here is just "this is impossible".  Does that fully address your question? If so I will write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Sounds like an answer @jcalz, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible in TypeScript (without something like a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), which you don't want to do).

Right now [the `arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) is given [the `IArguments` type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/905a0b4e693e8cc13a726ad650b908fee4f75408/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L373-L377), which is "array-like" in that it has a numeric [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) and a numeric `length` property, but it's not strongly typed enough to know which argument type is at which numeric index, or the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `length` property:

```
function f(a: number, b: number) {
    const arg0 = arguments[0];
    // const arg0: any
    const len = arguments.length;
    // const len: number
}
```

That is, `IArguments` is array-like, but it's not [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types)-like.  There is a longstanding open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#29055](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29055) to make `arguments` more strongly typed, and maybe at some point there'd be a special `IArguments<T>` type which acts like a tuple type stripped of its array-specific methods (it's a little tricky because currently only actual tuples are considered spreadable into function arguments, so if you try to write a custom `IArguments<T>` yourself and assign `arguments` to it, you wouldn't be able to call `f(...arguments)` without also allowing `arguments.map(x => x)` which isn't valid).

For now it's not part of the language, and if you want that behavior you'll need to use type assertions or the like.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAFAQwFyLCAtgIwFMAnAGkXyxwJIEpEBvAWAChF3EIEBnKRNYgHMADIgC8-IXkJgo3ANrCAugG5WHRAHpNnHnwEisaMAE91HLmF6IANjPGTB02dwB0dsIKgALNWw7aulZ8HlR4RMSs5ux2+kLcWAAKAmi4hFAk3AA8UCYADoRwwMgAfA4GznLRWjoAosTEcMRYACr5hIgA5ACSAIJSaS6diDDc2HD63NwwgmBo+HaIUHBL7V3ymNjhJOSUWzTESp2urAC+USysQA)